# How sexual activity influences a woman's sex drive

Tags: sexuality, sex-differences

[Sheila Gregoire suggests](http://powertochange.com/familylife/articles/sex-romance/married-women-increase-libido-by-having-more-sex/) that increasing the amount of sexual activity increases a woman's sexual desire in general.
I can postulate that child bearing and raising impacts significantly upon a woman's life and that possibly, when a woman finds a mate worthwhile, it is a primitive drive to reproduce.

In  studies by Winnifred B. Cutler, it is demonstrated how, as sexual frequency declines so does sex drive, for women.

[image]
 [HOW SEXUAL FREQUENCY AFFECTS
A WOMAN'S SEXUAL RESPONSIVENESS](http://site.themarriagebed.com/biology/female/how-frequency-effects-women),
FERTILITY, AND HEALTH
Paul H. Byerly

- **Is it true that having sex increases a women's future desire to have sex?**
- **What physiological purpose does this serve?**

Comment: Nice question. I'm a man and I'm not sure Cutler has it right for men. Anecdote: When I had sex, I am very horny the next day. If I don't have sex for some time, I forget about it. Anecdote: Canadian comic artist Dave Sim decided to become celibate. He says: "If you don't scratch it, it doesn't itch." Nuns and monks say something similar. Probably the reason for abstaining from sex has something to do with the increase or lack of increase in desire: if you want sex but can't have it, you'll want it more desperately with time. If you are otherwise occupied, you won't miss it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inverse of your first question might hold generally true: that desired sexual frequency could influence a woman's actual sexual frequency.

Willoughby and Vitas (2012) conducted a study focusing on the sexual desired discrepancy between male and females. They make reference to sexual desire discrepancy (SDD) - difference between one's desired frequency of sexual intercourse and actual frequency of sexual intercourse.

> High SDD may then lead some females to put more resources into the
>   relationship in order to work toward future sexual contact and
>   increase the intimacy and closeness in their relationship. In this
>   way, SDD may serve among female partners as a motivator to enhance and
>   support the relationship as it progresses toward higher sexual
>   frequency.

It mainly would depend on the quality and satisfaction of the sexual intercourse that would determine whether a woman's desire for greater sexual frequency would increase or not. Assuming that quality and satisfaction of sexual intercourse is high for the woman, I would say that this would increase a woman's future desire to have sex. Processes on positive expectancies give rise to higher perceived quality of the sexual relationship (McNulty & Fisher, 2008) and thus, in my opinion, if the woman expects sexual intercourse to be as good as a prior experience, they're more likely to desire it more.

So, perhaps deprivation or excess of sexual intercourse and expectancies of quality of sexual intercourse plays a major role in moulding sexual desire for women. Another thing: while the frequency of sex is predicated on the physical rewards of it for men, this may not be necessarily true for women.

---

**References**

- Willoughby, B.J. & Vitas, J. (2012). Sexual desire frequency: The effect of individual differences in desired and actual sexual frequency on dating couples. Archive of Sexual Behavior, 41, 477-486.
- McNulty, J.K. & Fisher, T.D. (2008). Gender differences in response to sexual expectancies and changes in sexual frequency: A short-term longitudinal study of sexual satisfaction in newly married couples. Archive of Sexual Behavior, 37, 229-240.